# Java JTabbedPane switch tab immediately

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a simple JTabbedPane component with two tabs. When a button event is fired on one of the tabs, I want the current view to be set to the other tab *immediately*. I can successfully get the current tab to switch using setSelectedIndex(int) in the actionPerformed method of the button in question, but the remaining functionality of the button event can sometimes take a while to complete.

It would seem that the setSelectedIndex(int) change doesn't occur immediately, and only happens when the body of the actionPerformed method that was triggered by the button click/press has completed.

The reason that I want to switch tabs when the button is clicked/pressed, is so that the user can see a message in a text area on the other tab telling them "processing, please wait" etc. while the remainder of the button click functionality is carried out. The results of that functionality, when they arrive, will replace the "...please wait" message.

So what's happening now is that I click the button, it freezes on that tab until the button functionality has completed entirely, and then it switches. So the "...please wait" message is actually never even seen.

I'm not sure what to do. Create a new thread for the "functionality", maybe, and let the button click event kick off the thread so that the button event can finish and switch tabs while waiting for results.
Just thinking out loud. Any help is appreciated.

-Rob

Comment: what you probably want to do is actually something different: if you think about it and if you look at complex applications (like IDEs), you'll notice they usually don't bother with *"Please wait"* messages embedded in every tab/subtab/subscreen/whatever of the app.  What they do is put a progress bar that can be seen from **any** part of the app and update that progress bar from whatever "part" of the app the user is in.  Not unlike how some browsers always show the *%* of each page loaded always in the same spot.  A much nicer design in my opinion.

Comment: A progress bar would be great, but I'm in a bit of a hurry with this, and I definitely wouldn't have time for the implementation of keeping track of time remaining. I understand what you mean, though, when you say simply put the message in some universal area of the app, I might consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you have a threading issue more than anything, that this is freezing your GUI making it completely unresponsive until it completes, and thus delaying your tabbed pane swap.  If you are running any long-running processes in your action performed method, do them instead in a background thread such as supplied by a SwingWorker, and then your GUI will become more responsive.

For details on this, please check out this tutorial: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

If despite this advice, you're still having problems, then you're likely going to have to post some of your offending code. Best would be if you could create a small compilable and runnable app that reproduces the problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

¡Que tengas suerte!

Comment: +1, understanding the EDT and the single thread rule is one of the most important concepts of learning Swing. A tutorial link is always important for this.

Comment: I eventually got it working using invokeLater(new Runnable { etc.. in the actionPerformed method. I will take a closer look at the EDT, though, just so I have a better understanding of whats going on.

Comment: After reading up some more on the EDT and SwingWorker, it seems you were right, and that SwingWorker really is the way to go for any background tasks that may take time to complete. The GUI now stays as responsive as it should be. Thanks.